# Foundation 6.2.4 responsive menu not working as it did with 6.0.0 (identical code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

This navigation bar worked as expected with Foundation 6.0.0. When changing the Foundation version to 6.2.4, the hidden button bar does not appear (nor does the top-bar disappear) on small screens.

Here is a fiddle of the Foundation 6.0.0 version that is working.
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/frur5y41/

```
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="realEstateMenu" data-hide-for="small">
    <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
    <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
</div>
<div class="top-bar" id="realEstateMenu">
    <div class="top-bar-left">
        <ul class="menu" data-responsive-menu="accordion">
            <li class="menu-text">Interplanetary</li>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>    
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Here is a fiddle of the same code using Foundation 6.2.4 (the responsiveness is not working).

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g56gn37w/

Any help identifying the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're asking people to do an awful lot to help understand whats wrong.  How about setting up a jsfiddle to show the issue

Comment: I put you fiddle code in a codepen and it doesn't work there with the lower versions setting. https://codepen.io/chris0/pen/dpLJNL

Comment: @ChrisO - did you include the 4 external resources - JS & CSS?

Comment: @CastleApplicationsGroup you'll need to flag this question to be re-opened by a moderator.

Comment: @ChrisO, thank you for your edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears changing to `data-hide-for="medium"` fixes the problem.

So the entire code block would be:

```
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="realEstateMenu" data-hide-for="medium">
    <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
    <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
</div>
<div class="top-bar" id="realEstateMenu">
    <div class="top-bar-left">
        <ul class="menu" data-responsive-menu="accordion">
            <li class="menu-text">Interplanetary</li>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>    
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/2dexkkj1/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
`data-hide-for="small"` worked in version 6.0.0
```

It is not working in version 6.2.4, instead use `data-hide-for="medium"`

Also, you can use `class="title-bar hide-for-small"` instead of the 'data-hide-for'.

I researched the issue but was unable to find any reference to the change from the previous version to this version. This does make more sense though as you wouldn't want to hide the hamburger menu from the small screen view.